# How do i add a div under or above every image in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

my image class is "mouseover".

i am using this code to add class="boxbut" under above last image.

```
    function ads_added_above_last_p6($text) {
    if( is_single()) :
        $ads_text = '<div class="boxbut" style="text-align: center;"> 
</div>
';
        if($pos1 = strrpos($text, '<img class="mouseover">')){
            $text1 = substr($text, 0, $pos1);
            $text2 = substr($text, $pos1);
            $text = $text1 . $ads_text . $text2;
        }


        endif;
    return $text;
    }
add_filter('the_content', 'ads_added_above_last_p6');
```

How do i add this div under all images.or hover all images.

Comment: can you be more specific, also can you show us the html code you obtain and tell us how you it to be ?

Comment: i want to use it for wordpress..html wil be like
<p class="some_p_class"><img class="mouseover" src="some.jpg"></p>

i want to add a div under all images with text "shop now".

my code is works but showing the div only under last pera.

it will be good if the div shows on image hover. but i don't know how to do thaa

Comment: You should avoid using client-side processing with JS to do this if its not necessary, although its difficult to work out exaclty what you need from your question. Seeing the HTML *exactly* as it is generated on your site would help. Have you debugged this function to see why `if($pos1 = strrpos($text, '<img class="mouseover">')){` is failing? e.g. printing out the value to see what it is, if it has unexpected spaces, extra classes added by some other function or JS etc. Would it be possible to see a working demo of the site?